# how to identify and get buy/sale/net transaction monthly

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table named 'balance' like this

```
user_id    date         transaction_amount 
123        2021-08-30   1000
123        2021-08-31   500 
456        2021-09-30   -750 
789        2021-09-30   50
```

i need to know total buy/sell/net transaction on monthly level (end-of-period/eop)
which :

```
buy = transaction > 0
sell = transaction < 0
net = total buy = total sell
```

how to write the code?

so far i've tried

```
eop_trans = df_balance.groupby([df_balance['user_id'], df_balance['date'].dt.to_period('M')])['transaction_amount'].sum()
eop_trans
```

that code only return total amount of transaction per user_id per month

anyone can help? thank you very much

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: And what is ouput if change `789` to `456` ?

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. thank you very much. so much detail and a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for distinguish `buy/sell`, aggregate `sum` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last if necessary sum both columns use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
eop_trans = (df_balance.groupby([df_balance['user_id'], 
                    df_balance['date'].dt.to_period('M'),
                    np.where(df_balance['transaction_amount'].gt(0), 'buy', 'sell')])
         ['transaction_amount']
         .sum()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .assign(net = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
         .reset_index())
print (eop_trans)
   user_id     date   buy  sell   net
0      123  2021-08  1500     0  1500
1      456  2021-09     0  -750  -750
2      789  2021-09    50     0    50
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dataframe is called `df`, first, make sure that the colum `date` is of datetime

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then, if I understood correctly, the following will do the work

```
df_new = df.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).sum().reset_index()

df_new['buy'] = np.where(df_new['transaction_amount'] > 0, df_new['transaction_amount'], 0)

df_new['sell'] = np.where(df_new['transaction_amount'] < 0, df_new['transaction_amount'], 0)

df_new['net'] = df_new['buy'] + df_new['sell']

df_new = df_new[['user_id', 'date', 'buy', 'sell', 'net']]

[Out]:

   user_id       date   buy  sell   net
0      123 2021-08-31  1500     0  1500
1      456 2021-09-30     0  -750  -750
2      789 2021-09-30    50     0    50
```

---

Let us breakdown the steps to make it clearer.

Start by grouping by `user_id` with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

```
df_new = df.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).sum().reset_index()

[Out]:

   user_id       date  transaction_amount
0      123 2021-08-31                1500
1      456 2021-09-30                -750
2      789 2021-09-30                  50
```

Then, let us first create the column `buy`. For that one will be using [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df_new['buy'] = np.where(df_new['transaction_amount'] > 0, df_new['transaction_amount'], 0)

[Out]:

   user_id       date  transaction_amount   buy
0      123 2021-08-31                1500  1500
1      456 2021-09-30                -750     0
2      789 2021-09-30                  50    50
```

For the column `sell` one will be using [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as well

```
df_new['sell'] = np.where(df_new['transaction_amount'] < 0, df_new['transaction_amount'], 0)

[Out]:

   user_id       date  transaction_amount   buy  sell
0      123 2021-08-31                1500  1500     0
1      456 2021-09-30                -750     0  -750
2      789 2021-09-30                  50    50     0
```

For the `net` column, one will do the following

```
df_new['net'] = df_new['buy'] + df_new['sell']

[Out]:

   user_id       date  transaction_amount   buy  sell   net
0      123 2021-08-31                1500  1500     0  1500
1      456 2021-09-30                -750     0  -750  -750
2      789 2021-09-30                  50    50     0    50
```

Finally, as one doesn't want `transaction_amount` to show up, one can select the desired columns as follows

```
df_new = df_new[['user_id', 'date', 'buy', 'sell', 'net']]

[Out]:

   user_id       date   buy  sell   net
0      123 2021-08-31  1500     0  1500
1      456 2021-09-30     0  -750  -750
2      789 2021-09-30    50     0    50
```